# One Intent per each FAQ entry?

Tags: amazon-lex

I was asked to create an Amazon Lex chat bot containing around 40 entries from an existing online FAQ.

I ended up having to create one intent per FAQ entry.

For each intent I added the question as an utterance and the answer as a conclusion statement.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

For example, to have all questions and answers in a single intent, such as a FaqIntent.

I hope I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one intent per FAQ is correct way, all the FAQ's can be asked in different ways so just don't forget to add multiple and distinct utterances for each intent.

Example: FAQ -> What are the user policy?
This can be asked as "give me the user policies", "where can i find the user policies" etc.

If you have only one intent for all FAQ's then you will have to handle many things at your end, and using Lex will be pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Check the AWS QnABot example:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-question-and-answer-bot-with-amazon-lex-and-amazon-alexa/
It uses Lamdba/Elastic Search in the backend so you don't have to create all the possible utterance.